# Is "authentification" a real word?

Tags: word-choice, nouns, is-it-a-word

My professor used the word *authentification* in a lecture. I have always used authentication. Is it a real word or is authentication the correct term?

Comment: Several other languages use the form with "fi" and even though the "authentication" is correct in english, "authentification" suggests itself. _Also "Authentification" in this exact form comes from french._

Comment: Because of the spelling "authentication" in English, I was thinking we also write "identication" instead of "identification"...

Answer (score 64, accepted):

*Authentication* is the preferred form in English. The variant *authentification* is acceptable, but less common—it’s often used by non-native speakers who aren’t aware that it’s less idiomatic in English, because *authentification* (or an analogue) is the correct form (or at least widely accepted) in many eastern & western European languages:

- Azerbaijani: autentifikasiyası
- Basque: autentifikazio
- Belarusian: аўтэнтыфікацыя (autentyfikatsyja)
- Bosnian: autentifikacija
- Corsican: autentificazione
- Czech: autentifikace
- Danish: autentificering
- Dutch: autenti(fi)catie
- French: authentification
- German: Authenti(fi)kation
- Haitian: otantifikasyon
- Kazakh: аутентификация (autyentifikatsiya)
- Italian: autentificazione
- Latvian: autentifikācija
- Lithuanian: autentifikavimas
- Luxembourgish: authentifikatioun
- Romanian: autentificare
- Russian: аутентификация (autyentifikatsiya)
- Spanish: autenti(fi)cación
- Ukrainian: автентифікація (avtyentifikatsiya)
- Uzbek: autentifikatsiya

(Source: Google Translate—transliterations from Cyrillic are a best effort and may not be standard/accurate for all languages.)

According to the [Online Etymology Dictionary](https://www.etymonline.com/word/authentication) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authentication), *authentication* was the original form, via Latin *authenticare*, from Greek *αὐθεντικός* (*authentikos*), from *αὐθέντης* (*authentis*) “author” + *-ικός* (*-ikos*) “relating to”—cf. Latin *-ic(us)*.

According to the Oxford English Dictionary, the change to *authenti**fi**cation* seems to have happened in the mid-18th century—in English at least. It likely arose by analogy with similar words such as *personification*, *modification*, *ratification*, *unification*, &c., which all include the Latin element *-fic-*, from *ficare*, the combining form of *facere*, “to make”.

Comment: In German it is also spelled _Authentifikation_, and I see it getting mistranslated to _authentification_ every time.

Comment: In Russian it is also spelled with *fi*: Аутентификация (Autentificatsiya).

Comment: We have clients: From Austria, Germany and Spain, many of them are English speakers but they insists to use Authentification!!!

Comment: It looks like authentification has been gaining popularity; it's about 4x more popular today than it was in the 60s. That being said, authentication is still approximately 700-800 times more prevalent. Link to Google ngram viewer: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=authentification&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cauthentification%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bauthentification%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAuthentification%3B%2Cc0

Comment: In Czech it is also "Autentifikace", that's why I am having such a hard time to get it right when using english.

Comment: If German, Russian, Spanish and Czech all use Authentification, then surely that is the correct form.

Comment: Same in Dutch ('authentificatie'), and I think that knowing it like that from another language is the most common reason people use the wrong word in English.

Comment: @BaneStar007 It says nothing about what's correct in English

Comment: How does 'The variant _authentification_ is likely just a mistake by a non-native speaker' correspond to [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/authentification)'s accepting it as a word without caveats?

Comment: -1 because both are in the OED. Which is about the same as saying they're both "real worlds." and

Comment: Maybe we should just start driving on the right like all those other countries ...

Comment: @Clare: Alright, I changed “correct” to “preferred”.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I was under the impression that native speakers of English generally prefer the older variant without *-fi-*, and it’s more common to use the variant with *-fi-* among non-native speakers. If you have a better word than “mistake” then I’ll take it.

Comment: Your last paragraph (the part about how the longer variant probably entered the lexicon) is on the surface at odds with your first. I'd go with 'The variant _authentification_ is likely just an example of a use by a non-native speaker not realising that this is less idiomatic, because ...'

Comment: Where is the authentification for "it’s often used by non-native speakers who aren’t aware that it’s less idiomatic in English..."? That seems absolutely unsupported.

Comment: No, "autentifikace" doesn't exist in Czech language, professors are throwing you out if you say it during exam on IT university.

Comment: I'm sorry to inform you, but this word is simply incorrect. You are mixing the languages, no native English speaker would ever say "authentification".

Answer (score 12):

*Authentification* is a French word. After a bit on research on its origin, it would seem that the word is actually composed of three parts :

- authentique (authentic)
- fic → faire (to do)
- ation → action

Source: http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/authentification

Comment: Actually "faire" doesn't explain the "c" in there - I would guess that this came from the "c" in Latin "facere".  Also your use of "action" (which comes from "agere" + "-io" suffix) is kind of misleading, I'd say it's actually the "-io" suffix at work on a form of "facere", nothing to do with the verb at root in "action".

Comment: and the 'c' is a remnant of Latin's c in the verb facio (I do), facere, feci, factum from which faire derives.

Comment: So it is NOT an English word. This should be the accepted answer.